# AttributeError: 'CRF' object has no attribute 'keep_tempfiles'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, crf

I am currently trying to replicate certain methods from this blog https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-and-classification-with-scikit-learn-f05372f07ba2  using the crfsuite library which is supposed to have an attribute called `keep_tempfiles = False` as shown in https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn_crfsuite/estimator.html.

However, when I run this piece of code in my jupyter notebook

```
crf = sklearn_crfsuite.CRF(algorithm='lbfgs',c1=0.1,c2=0.1,max_iterations=100,all_possible_transitions=True)
crf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs)
    462     def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):
    463         """Mime bundle used by jupyter kernels to display estimator"""
--> 464         output = {"text/plain": repr(self)}
    465         if get_config()["display"] == 'diagram':
    466             output["text/html"] = estimator_html_repr(self)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    258             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    259 
--> 260         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    261 
    262         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

/usr/lib/python3.8/pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

/usr/lib/python3.8/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

/usr/lib/python3.8/pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    402 
    403     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 404         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    405                                                 self._depth, level)
    406         if not readable:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    178 
    179     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 180         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
    181                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    182 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    423         recursive = False
    424         if changed_only:
--> 425             params = _changed_params(object)
    426         else:
    427             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     89     estimator with non-default values."""
     90 
---> 91     params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     92     init_func = getattr(estimator.__init__, 'deprecated_original',
     93                         estimator.__init__)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    193         out = dict()
    194         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 195             value = getattr(self, key)
    196             if deep and hasattr(value, 'get_params'):
    197                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'CRF' object has no attribute 'keep_tempfiles'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395 
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    682     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    683     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 684     output = repr(obj)
    685     lines = output.splitlines()
    686     with p.group():

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    258             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    259 
--> 260         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    261 
    262         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

/usr/lib/python3.8/pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

/usr/lib/python3.8/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

/usr/lib/python3.8/pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    402 
    403     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 404         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    405                                                 self._depth, level)
    406         if not readable:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    178 
    179     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 180         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
    181                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    182 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    423         recursive = False
    424         if changed_only:
--> 425             params = _changed_params(object)
    426         else:
    427             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     89     estimator with non-default values."""
     90 
---> 91     params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     92     init_func = getattr(estimator.__init__, 'deprecated_original',
     93                         estimator.__init__)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    193         out = dict()
    194         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 195             value = getattr(self, key)
    196             if deep and hasattr(value, 'get_params'):
    197                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'CRF' object has no attribute 'keep_tempfiles'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

- related issue on github     : https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/issues/60

Comment: Thank you, downgrading to sklearn <0.24 did work to solve this issue for now.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply pass the error, the prediction should still work.

```
try:
    crf.fit(X_train, y_train)
except AttributeError:
    pass
predictions = crf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: works without the need for downgrade version

Comment: This works for a single fit. However this doesn't seem to be suitable when performing hyperparameter optimisation using `RandomizedSearchCV()` and so on. Is there a way to handle that error in this case?